# Preparing a release but I want to do my first release without the play store or ios store

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Just a quick question. Is it possible to release my app to a few select ios and android phones? I would like to test the app before I put it on any sort of store. Also what are the options for release, meaning: this app is for a small company and I don't want other people being able to use it. Is it possible to release it only to a select group of people?

Comment: appcenter.ms can do this for iOS and Android.  Or Apple's TestFlight, but only for iOS obviously.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android can install APK's from outside the google play store.  Just send the apk to your testers.
Here is a tutorial: https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-install-apks-31494/

For iOS, you have to go through testflight (significantly more steps):
https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: Feel free to explain the downvote so I can become better at giving answers :D